# (SQL) look for entity in the other string column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'd like to look for `a.id` from TableA which is more than 1 `b.this_id` is `IN a.id_list`.

example table

```sql
TableA as a
id    name  id_list  
1     xyz   /0/1
2     efd   /0/1/2  
3     abc   /0/2/3 
4     pqr   /0/2/3/4

TableB as b
this_id     
2         
3  
4
```

if we count `this_id` on tableA,

```sql
TableA as a
id    number of this_id  id_list
1     0                  /0/1
2     1                  /0/1/2  
3     2                  /0/2/3 
4     3                  /0/2/3/4
```

since id 3,4 have more than 1 `this_id`, I'd like to select id 3,4.
but since id_list is string, it's quite tricky for me to do that.
Is there any way to implement it?

*I made this sql but apparently not works.

```sql
SELECT a.id 
FROM tableA a
WHERE a.id_list IN (select b.this_id from tableB b)
and a.id IN (select b.this_id from tableB b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `join` and aggregation.  One way uses `find_in_set()`:

```
select a.id
from tableA a join
     tableB b
     on find_in_set(b.this_id, replace(a.id_list, '/', ',')) > 0
group by a.id
having count(*) >= 2;
```

That said, storing multiple values in a string is a bad idea.  You should have a separate table with one row per id pair.  This is a junction table.

Why is storing ids in a string a bad idea?  Well:

- You should use the right type, and a string is not a number.
- You should declare foreign key relationships.
- SQL has poor string functionality.
- The use of strings generally prevents using indexes and other optimizations.

Comment: I got this error 
Error occurred.SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'b' in 'on clause'

Comment: it's the place for column not table?!

Comment: if i change like this,  `find_in_set(b.this_id, replace...)` then I have `timeout undefined` error..

Comment: @JunoJ . . . As the answer explains that your method of storing this data is a very bad idea.

Comment: I understood that point but current DB structure is like that and I cannot promtly edit it. we need investigation for current DB first then we can change it : )